# Minina and maxima (2-variable function)

Tags: calculus

I need to find a minima and maxima of a function $z = x^2 - 12x + y^2 - 2y$ that is limited by points $A(-7,-5)$, $B(5;-5)$ and $C(5,10)$ but i do not clearly understand the algorithm $><$

What should i do? Especially with equation of $CA$ line ($y = 1.25x + 3.75$)

Comment: it's pairs **(x,y)** and it's actually a triangle based on them, so we're looking for min/max of a function in this triangle

Comment: what is the algorithm you don't understand?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be setting the Jacobian Matrix equal to $0$ and solve the systems of equation. In this way you will find all points that could be potentially minima or maxima. Now you have to check wich of these points meet the condition of beeing limited by $A,B,C$. Anyway are those points $(x,y),(y,z)$ or $(x,z)$ ?